# How can I add the WSS TimeToLive element to a SOAP request body?

Tags: soap, soapui

I'm in the process of creating an SSIS package to consume a SOAP web service, using ZappySys' SSIS PowerPack. ZappySys has a tutorial on how to build a SOAP request by taking the body that SoapUI generates. The following is what gets generated by SoapUI:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:urn="urn:xxx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxx:ZZZZ-ZZZZZZ">
   <soap:Header>
      <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="true" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
         <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-999CBF85A26FC675D3148400614200053">
            <wsu:Created>2017-01-09T23:55:42.000Z</wsu:Created>
            <wsu:Expires>2017-01-09T23:56:42.000Z</wsu:Expires>
         </wsu:Timestamp>
         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-999CBF85A26FC675D3148399868052714">
            <wsse:Username>User</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">HashedPasswordGoesHere</wsse:Password>
            <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">HashedNonce</wsse:Nonce>
            <wsu:Created>2017-01-09T21:51:20.527Z</wsu:Created>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <urn:ZZZZZZ>
         <MESSAGE_IN>?</MESSAGE_IN>
         <PRODUCT_DATAs>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <PRODUCT_DATA>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <PRODUCT_ID>?</PRODUCT_ID>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <VISTA_CUST_NUM>?</VISTA_CUST_NUM>
            </PRODUCT_DATA>
         </PRODUCT_DATAs>
      </urn:ZZZZZZ>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

If the "WSS TimeToLive" property is not set, this request fails. If it is set to anything >0, the request succeeds. Looking at the SoapUI documentation, it says that if the "WSS TimeToLive" property is set, then SoapUI automatically adds an element to the request, but I can't find the syntax/format for the TimeToLive element.

Adding the Timestamp and the Created and Expires elements seems to have no bearing on whether the request fails or not. Does anyone know how to explicitly specify the WSS TimeToLive in the request body?

Comment: If you set the `WSS TimeToLive` property value, then soapui takes care automatically. Could not get the actual concern of yours. Why do you want set if manually in the request? Please clarify.

Comment: Do you want to create the request automatically using some kind of programming, and not like to use soapui? Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @Rao, yes, I'm looking to create an SSIS package to pull data from the SOAP response and store it in a database. Even in SoapUI, if I add a timestamp with create/expire times, but no WSS TimeToLive value in properties, the connection will fail.